# UWP - Detect when child property's value changes?

Tags: c#, events, binding, uwp, prism

I'm creating an application using UWP and Prism. I have an object `ParentObject` which has child properties such as `int Child`. I want to call `SomeMethod(ParentObject)` when the child property of the `ParentObject` changes. These objects are bound to in the UI, and everything works correctly there.

My initial intuition was that the `set` accessor on the `ParentObject` would be called when a child property changes (see the commented line below), however it is not. Only the `set` accessor for `int Child` is called.
How can I achieve the same effect?

```
public class MyViewModel : BindableBase
{
    private ParentObject _parent;
    public ParentObject Parent
    {
        get { return _parent; }
        set
        {
            _parent = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(Parent);
            // SomeMethod(Parent);
        }
    }

    public void SomeMethod(ParentObject obj) { ... }
}

public class ParentObject : BindableBase
{
    private int _child;
    public int Child
    {
        get { return _child; }
        set
        {
            _child = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(Child);
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 0):

In your MyViewModel.Parent property setter, you need to detach the previous and then attach a new PropertyChanged event on the value.

```
public class MyViewModel : BindableBase
{
    private ParentObject _parent;
    public ParentObject Parent
    {
        get { return _parent; }
        set
        {
            if (_parent != null)
            {
               _parent.PropertyChanged -= OnChildPropertyChanged;
            }
            _parent = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(Parent);

            if (value != null)
            {
               value.PropertyChanged += OnChildPropertyChanged;
            }

            SomeMethod(Parent);
        }
    }

    public void SomeMethod(ParentObject obj) { ... }

    private void OnChildPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs args) 
    {
        SomeMethod(Parent);
    }
}
```

Comment: That doesn't work unfortunately. When `ParentObject.Child` has its value changed, neither `OnChildPropertyChanged` or `SomeMethod` are called. The child value does change inside of the `Parent` object, but the methods are not called.

Comment: You need to uncomment SomeMethod() in the Parent setter

Comment: Unfortunately this did not work for me - I ended up rethinking my code structure to avoid needing this at all. But thank you anyway. Hopefully this is helpful for someone else!